# SASS variable assignment inside mixin ignored

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

I wanted to make a dynamic SASS theme switcher so I did this after some [research](https://gist.github.com/kaplas/6424861):

```
$valueName: ("ui_main");
$valueLight: (yellow);
$valueDark: (grey);

$currentTheme: "";

@mixin theme() {

  $currentTheme: "light";
  .light & {
    @content
  }

  $currentTheme: "dark";
  .dark & {
    @content
  }

}

@function getValue($name) {

  $index: index($valueName, $name);

  @if ($index == false) {
    @error $valueName + " has not been defined";
  }

  @if ($currentTheme == "light") {

    @return nth($valueLight, $index);

  } @else if ($currentTheme == "dark") {

    @return nth($valueLight, $index);

  } @else {
    @error "Invalid Theme: '" + $currentTheme + "'";
  }

}
```

My Main SASS file looks like this:

```
@import "themer"

div
  @include theme
    background: getValue("ui_main")
```

But the variable **$currentTheme** won't change. The console gives me my own error:

```
cmd.exe /D /C call C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\sass.bat --no-cache --update theme.sass:theme.css
      error themer.scss (Line 38: Invalid Theme: '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `!global` modifier when modifying global variable from local scope:

```
@mixin theme() {
  $currentTheme: "light" !global;
  .light & {
    @content
  }

  $currentTheme: "dark" !global;
  .dark & {
    @content
  }
}
```